# How to retrieve the properties->environment variables of all folders inside one jenkins folder using groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to groovy scripting. my question is,
For example If I have structure like

[image]

```
node {
    echo sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'env')
    // ...
}
```

This would always give me the env variables for top Folder. How to loop through the structure to get env for all the folders?

Comment: For my understanding: what do you mean by env variables for a folder? Environment variables are usually process-related and don’t have anything to do with the file system.

Comment: i mean env variables from configure->properties->environment variables.
Basically i want to loop through the all the jobs which are in the similar structure that  I have given, and fetch the env variables for the all the jobs at once.

Comment: Sorry but still don’t get your question. You already read the variables using a node block. With folders are you referring to the folders you can create in Jenkins and put jobs inside?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. but you got it correct. I am talking about the folders which we can create in jenkins.

Comment: Think it'd be possible to iterate through those folders using the inner Jenkins Folder plugin API: https://github.com/jenkinsci/cloudbees-folder-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/hudson/plugins/folder/AbstractFolder.java. You'll need to check the API's and see whether you can find the point where to access the environment variables. However as I would not consider this a very clean approach and it will require both `@NonCPS` and working outside the sandbox it'd probably be good to know your use case in order to suggest a different solution.

Comment: ... and of course: As soon as you're going to use `@NonCPS` it'll get more difficult to use the information you got in some pipeline step like `sh`.